# So im trying to make my player get damage but delayed like example the enemy damage you (amount of damage) per second

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

code below here(So im trying to make my player get damage but delayed like  example the enemy damage you (amount of damage) per second)Also i got the base of the code from brackey but i modified it a little bit

```
private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    
    if ( hit.collider.tag == "Zombie" )
    {

        InvokeRepeating("ZombieDamage", 2f, 1f);
    }

}
IEnumerator Iframe()
{
    float ZombieIFrame = 2f;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(ZombieIFrame);
}



void takedamage(int damage)
{
   
    
        damage -= armor.getValue();
        Mathf.Clamp(damage, 0, int.MaxValue);

        currentHealth -= damage;
        Debug.Log(transform.name + " takes " + damage + " damage ");

    

    if (currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        die();
    }
}

void die()
{
    Debug.Log(transform.name + "Died");
   
}
```

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The question isnt clear, but I assume you are talking about a dot (damage over time)? I recommend using a Coroutine (IEnumerator) wich would receive some parameters like, total damage, tick count, time, etc. You would then call a function to take damage, pause the routine (yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f) ), take some more damage and so on.

If ever the character dies while the dot isnt over, be sure to cancel the coroutine or you'll be trying to deal damage to a dead character and get errors.